# How to get copy of void pointer data

Tags: c, pointers, copy, void, void-pointers

I try to implement linked list on my own. So when I add new data to it I use something like `node->data = data` where `data is (void*) type`. So I want to prevent data corruption by accidentally editing added variable.

For example:

```
int data = 10;
LinkedList_add(list, (void*)&data);
...
/* It will modify value in list */
data = new value;
```

How can I do this?
I tried to copy it this way:

```
 void* data_copy;
 *data_copy = *_data;
```

But I felt that it wouldn't work and it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure you do C? The `new` operator is C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to require the caller to specify how long the data he gives to you is. Change the signature of your `LinkedList_add` function to this:

```
void LinkedList_add(List*, size_t, const void*);
```

and then do something like this, where `size` is the size you got from the caller.

```
void *copy = malloc(size);
if (copy == NULL) {
    /* error handling here */
}

memcpy(copy, data, size);
```

In a real world, I would not bother doing something like this. Instead I would require the caller to copy the data I put into the linked list. If the caller doesn't want to have his data accidentally overwritten, he must make a copy himself. If he wants to be able to overwrite the data (which is a common use case) or if he doesn't care if its overwritten by accident, he might not want to have the data copied. Don't try to put the programmer under tutelage, that seldomly pays off in C.